# SQL Need a row to show up for a column that isn't

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the number of customers each sales rep has with this code.

```
select count(c.REP_NUM)'NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS',r.REP_NUM
  from CUSTOMER c, REP r
  where r.REP_NUM=c.REP_NUM
  group by r.REP_NUM
```

this is what it outputs

```
4   15
4   30
4   45
```

However there is another rep named rep 60 that has no customers but I need it to show up with a zero next to it to show that rep 60 has no customers.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit left join:

```
SELECT r.REP_NUM, COUNT(c.REP_NUM) AS NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS
FROM REP r
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER c
    ON r.REP_NUM = c.REP_NUM
GROUP BY r.REP_NUM;
```